# library dependencies in META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file

Tags: java, tomcat, jar

What's the meaning of **library dependencies** in MANIFEST.MF file stores in Tomcat. I don't understand it, while reading this in book. I need some clarification on it.

Why do we ever need to create MANIFEST.MF file in Tomcat, if the jar file in Tomcat is enough to handle all the requirements.

Thanks in advance for any valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the [Class-Path header in manifest files](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)? Not sure what the Tomcat part of the question is asking about though... internal jar files that implement Tomcat?  Libraries in a WAR file? The WAR file itself?